# How to render Reducer by applying filter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-redux

My Reducer is:

```
const initialState = {
  1: {
     id: '1',
     user: 'User1',
     text: 'User1 Comment',
     parentId: 0,
    },
  2: {
     id: '2',
     user: 'User2',
     text: 'User2 Comment',
     parentId: 0,
    },
  3: {
     id: '3',
     user: 'User1',
     text: 'User1 SubComment',
     parentId: 2,
    },
  4: {
     id: '4',
     user: 'User2',
     text: 'User2 SubComment',
     parentId: 3,
    },
  5: {
     id: '5',
     user: 'User1',
     text: 'User1 SubComment',
     parentId: 2,
    },
}
```

I have `mappedStateToProps` and able to show all the data using `Object.keys` and mapping it:

```
const renData = Object.keys(this.props.comments).map((key, idx) => {
  let comment = this.props.comments[key]
    return(
      <View key={idx}>
        <Text>
        { comment.id } - { comment.user } - { comment.text} - { comment.parentId }
        </Text>
          { renDataChild (comment.id) } // NOT SURE ABOUT THIS
      </View>
    )
  })
```

I want to show only the `objects` that have `parentId: 0` and show the other objects below the respective parent objects. What i want to achieve is :

[image]

What I understand is that I need to add a filter that will only show the objects which have `parentId: 0` and below that add a function (`const renDataChild`) that will take the current `id` and show only the objects that match the `parentId` with the passed `id`. Is this the proper way to do it? How do I add the filter and create `const renDataChild` for child objects?

Please help. Many thanks.

**UPDATE1:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Alert } from 'react-native';

var styles = require('../styles'); 
var styles1 = require('../styles1'); 

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class CommentsNew extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super();
  }

  componentDidMount() {

  }

 renderComments(commentId = 0) {
  return Object.keys(this.props.comments)
    .filter(id => this.props.comments[id].parentId === commentId)
    .map((key, idx) => {
      const comment = this.props.comments[key];
      const style = commentId === 0 ? styles.comment : styles.subComment;
      <View style={style} key={idx}>
        <Text>
          { comment.id } - { comment.user } - { comment.text} - { comment.parentId }
        </Text>
        {this.renderComments(comment.id)}
      </View>
    });
}

  render() {

     return this.renderComments();

  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    comments: state.comments
  }
}

export default connect( mapStateToProps ) (CommentsNew);
```

Error: 
CommentsNew.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Have tried:

```
  render() {
     return (
       this.renderComments();
     )
  }
```

Same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should render your comments recursively because when you render a comment you have to loop through the comments array to find if there are sub comments under the current comment. Something like that (this code isn't tested, maybe some errors):

```
renderComments(commentId = 0) {
  return Object.keys(this.props.comments)
    .filter(id => this.props.comments[id].parentId === commentId)
    .map((key, idx) => {
      const comment = this.props.comments[key];
      const style = commendId === 0 ? styles.comment : styles.subComment;
      return (
        <View style={style} key={idx}>
          <Text>
            { comment.id } - { comment.user } - { comment.text} - { comment.parentId }
          </Text>
          {this.renderComments(comment.id)}
        </View>
      );
    });
}

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      {this.renderComments()}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and getting error. Updated my question in `Update1` with the error. Error `A valid React element (or null) must be returned`. What am I missing here? `renderComments` function is outside `render()`.

Comment: `console.log` crashes the app. Not only this but any other simple app too. So cannot do console.log to check.

Comment: Tried wrapping `return` from the `renderComments` in `()` and/or the `render() return()` too.. but getting the same error.

Comment: I had forgotten to return the jsx part in the `.map()` callback, I edited with the correction.

Comment: Ok, it's because `renderComments` function return an array of `View` so you have to wrap the function call in a `View` like in my latest edit.

Comment: So close. Thank you very much for your time and teaching. Only 1 last problem now. I am only able to list all the comments with `commentId = 0` cause that is what is passed in the original function. So calling  `{this.renderComments(comment.id)}` in the function is somehow not passing the current `comment.id`. How do I go about this. Thanks a lot..

Comment: I also tried `{this.renderCommentsMy01(commentId = comment.id)}` but nothing changed. Please help.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, each call of `renderComments` are called with a different `commendId` so it should work ?

Comment: Change from strict equals `===`  to equals `== `  in your filter function. The `comment.id` is (for some reason) a string, so it will never be strict equals to `parentId` which is a number.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I've noticed that cause I'm little confused learning ES6 syntax, I'm ignoring the basics of JS. Thank you. This works like a charm. Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasArbona