# Update passing parameter to function in Javascript/React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Trying this in React-Native.

My function is :

```
myFunction(theId = 0) {
  return Object.keys(this.props.posts)
    .filter(/* ADDED FILTER */)
    .map((key, idx) => {
      const post = this.props.posts[key];
      return (
        <View key={idx}>

          <Text>
            { post.theId } - { post.name }
          </Text>

          {this.myFunction(post.theId)}  //THIS IS NOT GETTING EXECUTED

        </View>
      );
    });
}
```

I'm passing the value zero to `theId` as `myFunction(theId = 0)` But when I'm calling it again from within the function and want to pass the value of the returned data, it's not working. What do I need to do here to pass the value for theId? I also tried `{this.myFunction(theId=post.theId)}` but did not work.

Please help.

Comment: @Chris .. I'm still learning ES6 and not sure how would I do this. I tried `myFunction = (theId = 0) =>  {` But it failed with error `undefined is not a function`

Comment: Is this a typo: `<Viewkey={idx}>`?  there should be a space between `View` and `key`.

Comment: Can you say more about what the function is supposed to do? Why does it need to be calling itself? Would also be nice to see some example data for `this.props.posts`.

Comment: And please be more specific than " it's not working". Describe what happens, paste potential errors from the console.

Comment: @jonahe .. Other posts which whose theId is not equal to 0 don't show at all. Ref question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46139468/how-to-render-reducer-by-applying-filter/

Comment: Wrote a comment in the other tread about `===` vs. `==` in your filter function. That could very well be the issue here too.

Answer (score 0):

You never reference the argument variable in the code provided.

```
{this.myFunction(post.theId)}
```

That code is looking for a property named `theId` on the object `post`.  It is not looking at the given argument.

I take that what you actually want is to call `this.myFunction(post.theId)` and, if `post.theId` is undefined, to instead pass in `0`?  In that case, you would write it like this;

```
{this.myFunction(post.theId || 0)}
```

And you would completely remove the argument from the top of the function definition.